# Remove CSS class from <head><style> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using DOM and creating elements and CSS classes dynamically. How can I remove a CSS class that I have created previously using JavaScript only?

I use this code to create CSS class node:

```
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '.s1_o1{position:absolute;left:487px;top:243px;width:226px;height:61px;background-color:#ffffff;color:#ff0000;font: 18px Arial;}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

I want to remove the `s1_o1` class.

Comment: When you say "remove CSS class", what do you mean? An example would have been nice. From inside of `<style></style>` element in the `<head>`?

Comment: yes I want to remove the entire css class from <head><syle>

Answer (score 0):

For cross browser compatibility you will need to do something like this.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

head.className = head.className.replace(/\bClassName\b/,'');
```

Comment: I tried your code but nothing :-( Please see the question again I have modified it...